# Altering SE sites to imitate SO's appearance

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, dom, userscript

Some time ago someone complained that sites that were not stackoverflow were hard to read at work since people might be screen watching. So I bashed some code and created [SO-ify](https://stackapps.com/questions/7629/stackoverflow-ify). Some time and several versions later, it is basically as done as I can get it with my current skill.

While I will accept any feedback, that sort I am specifically looking for is optimization. Since I'm screwing around with a page as it loads, I want to work as quickly as possible, and ideally without being noticeable to the user.
This is a tamper/greasemonkey script, so if you like, you can [install here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/34034-so-ify).

I know parts of this are not very DRY, and if there is a way to fix that without without sacrificing speed, then I'm open to it. I have put the code below in its current state, if you'd rather I comment it up any more to explain decisions, I can definitely do that.

The original site this was created for was [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com), so thats why some of the comments and variable names refer to "scifi". Though, to be clear, this does, and should, work on all SE sites (with like two exceptions).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SO-ify
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      2.2.5
// @description  Style SE sites like SO
// @author       amflare
// @include      https://*stackexchange.com
// @include      https://*stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      https://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      https://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      https://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      https://stackexchange.com/
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';
  var primaryCss = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css';
  var secondaryCss = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/secondary.css';
  var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var regex = /\/Sites\/(?!stackoverflow).*\.css/;

  // Remove scifi et al
  var checkScifi = setInterval(function() {
    let sheets = document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='stylesheet']");
    sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
      if (regex.test(sheet.href)) {
        sheet.remove();
        clearInterval(checkScifi);
      }
    });
  }, 100);

  // Add SO Style Sheet
  let link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = primaryCss;
  head.appendChild(link);

  // Add secondary stylesheet
  let secondary = document.createElement('link');
  secondary.rel = 'stylesheet';
  secondary.href = secondaryCss;
  document.head.appendChild(secondary);

  // Replace Favicon
  document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']").href = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico';

  // Remove Site Logo From Top Bar
  var checkLogo= setInterval(function() {
    let logo = document.querySelector('.-logo svg');
    if (logo !== null) {
      logo.remove();
      clearInterval(checkLogo);
    }
  }, 100);

  // Change Site Name in Browser Tab
  if (window.location.pathname == '/') {
    document.querySelector('title').innerText = 'Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers';
  } else {
    var title = document.querySelector('title').innerText.split(" - ");
    if (title.length > 2) {
      document.querySelector('title').innerText = title[0] +' - '+ title[1] +' - Stack Overflow';
    } else {
      document.querySelector('title').innerText = title[0] + ' - Stack Overflow';
    }
  }

  // Change Site Name In Search Placeholder
  var checkSearch= setInterval(function() {
    let search = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]');
    if (search !== null) {
      search.placeholder = 'Search on Stack Overflow...';
      clearInterval(checkSearch);
    }
  }, 100);

  // Fix font issue
  var addCss = setInterval(function() {
    let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    if (typeof body != "undefined") {
      body.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif';
      body.style.fontSize = '13px';
      body.style.lineHeight = '1.26666667';
      body.style.color = '#242729';
      clearInterval(addCss);
    }
  }, 100);

  // Re-add css files to cache bust
  setTimeout(function(){
    let reLink = document.createElement('link');
    reLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
    reLink.href = primaryCss;
    head.appendChild(reLink);
    // remove original because we can
    link.remove();
  },100);
})();
```

Comment: I tried it out, that's pretty neat!

Comment: `querySelector` seems like the biggest bottleneck https://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbytagname

Answer (score 1):

### Feedback

This is an interesting script. I understand the desire to update the styles but don't see the point in changing the titles and placeholder texts to contain *Stack OverFlow* since it isn't the case that the search would involve SO posts...

Do you still use this userscript? I see that [the linked code](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/34034-so-ify) has evolved (and I have feedback on that code but I'll save that for another review). The [styles from February 16th 2018](http://web.archive.org/web/20180216174901/https://stackoverflow.com/) are a bit different that those of today - especially with the new sidebar that was introduced back in June...

### Suggestions

#### Many elements are obtained via queried when properties could be used:

- `document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='stylesheet']");` -> [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/styleSheets) (though that wouldn't include the favicon - I see the latest verison updates that)

  I also considered suggesting that the filtering of stylesheets could be moved into the CSS selector - something like `document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='stylesheet']:not([href~='stackoverflow']")` - that way the `if` condition within the callback function passed to `sheets.forEach()` could be removed... This would be analogous to filtering in a database query instead of a scripting language.
- `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` -> [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body)
- `document.querySelector('title').innerText` -> [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title)
- `document.querySelector('input[name="q"]');` -> `document.forms[0].elements.q`

#### Use `const` instead of `let` wherever re-assignment is not needed

This will avoid unintentional variable clobbering. Even if properties of an object or elements of an array are assigned later, `const` can still be used

#### Variable created for `<head>` element but not always used when it could be

The first SO styleSheet is added via `head` but the second is added via `document.head`

#### D.R.Y. adding CSS files

`primaryCSS` and `secondaryCss` could be added to an array, and then for each of those paths, an iterator loop could create the link elements - possibly using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with a callback function - or that callback function could be a named function. Also, the stack exchange sites should have jQuery, which could also be used to dramatically shorten the code needed to create elements.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! WRT your musings: Yes, this is still in use. The reason I replace logo/title/placeholder is for visual obfuscation. And SO is still hosting their old SO.css files, so I am able to use those on the non-modified sites (they also work on modified sites, but are admittedly a bit strange).

Comment: WRT the `document.property` suggestions, thanks for those. The links are being updated in place, which is causing a bit of a problem with `document.styleSheets`, so I'll have to look into that further. The rest, though, appear to be operating better. I can't believe I was so inconsistent with me `document.head`! WRT to dry css, thanks. I'm also experimenting with this some more, but its a definite improvement to code cleanliness, so thank you. WRT jQuery, I am operating under the (potentially inaccurate) assumption that vanilla JS will naturally be faster than jQuery

Comment: Cool - I added another thought about the stylesheet filtering